# How to debug igrep in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have highly customized igrep.el for my special purpose.
The search works fine but I always get :

```
Grep exited abnormally with code 1 at Wed Feb  5 18:18:09
```

At the end.
How do I go about debugging the code? How to find out which part I modified is causing the problem? I never debugged in emacs before.

My second question, is there a way to "highlight" the token I am igrepping for in the igrep window?

I am trying Iqbal's solution by incorporating the highlight inside the grep comand like so:

```
;;;###autoload
(defun igrep (program regex files &optional options)
  (interactive
   (igrep-read-args))
  (if (null program)
      (setq program (or igrep-program "grep")))
  (if (null options)
      (setq options igrep-options))
  (if (not (listp files))       ; (stringp files)
      (setq files (list files)))
  (if (and (member ?~ (mapcar 'string-to-char files))
       (save-match-data
         (string-match "\\`[rj]?sh\\(\\.exe\\)?\\'"
               (file-name-nondirectory shell-file-name))))
      ;; (restricted, job-control, or standard) Bourne shell doesn't expand ~:
      (setq files
        (mapcar 'expand-file-name files)))
  (let* ((use-zgrep (cond ((eq igrep-use-zgrep t))
              (igrep-use-zgrep
               (let ((files files)
                 (compressed-p nil))
                 (while (and files (not compressed-p))
                   (if (save-match-data
                     (string-match "\\.g?[zZ]\\'" (car files)))
                   (setq compressed-p t))
                   (setq files (cdr files)))
                 compressed-p))
              (t nil)))
     (command (format "%s -n %s %s %s %s %s"
              (if (and use-zgrep
                   (save-match-data
                     (not (string-match "\\`z" program))))
                  (setq program (concat "z" program))
                program)
              (or options
                  (and igrep-case-fold-search
                   (equal regex (downcase regex))
                   "-i")
                    ;                 "")
                  "-i") ;; R-Modified - default to ignore case
              (or igrep-regex-option
                  (progn
                (if (save-match-data
                      (string-match "\\`-" regex))
                    (setq regex (concat "\\" regex)))
                ""))
              (shell-quote-argument regex)
              (if igrep-find
                  (if igrep-find-use-xargs
                  ""
                (shell-quote-argument "{}"))
                (mapconcat (lambda (file)
                     (let ((dir (file-name-directory file)))
                       (if dir
                           (expand-file-name
                        (file-name-nondirectory file)
                        (igrep-quote-file-name dir))
                         file)))
                       files " "))
              igrep-null-device)))
    (if igrep-find
    (setq command
          (igrep-format-find-command command files)))
    (cond ((eq igrep-save-buffers t) (save-some-buffers t))
      (igrep-save-buffers (save-some-buffers)))
    (if (fboundp 'compilation-start)    ; Emacs 22
        (let ((compilation-process-setup-function 'grep-process-setup))
          (or (fboundp 'igrep-mode)
              (define-derived-mode igrep-mode grep-mode "Igrep"))
          (compilation-start command
               ; 'igrep-mode
                             'grep-mode ;;Modified
                             nil
                             (cond ((eq compilation-highlight-regexp t))
                                   (compilation-highlight-regexp
                                    (if (eq program "fgrep")
                                        (regexp-quote regex)
                                      regex)))))
      (compile-internal command (format "No more %s matches" program)
                        "Igrep" nil grep-regexp-alist)))

  (with-current-buffer "*grep*"
    ;; Remove any previous highlights
    (dolist (pattern hi-lock-interactive-patterns)
      (unhighlight-regexp (car pattern)))
    ;; Highlight the current regex
    (highlight-regexp regex))

)
```

Comment: It seems that that `grep` itself is failing, to debug goto igrep buffer (`*igrep*`), the grep command used by igrep should be there in buffer at the top, check that the command and the arguments are right, you may also try running it from the terminal that can give some clue as well. BTW how is `igrep` different than builtin `rgrep`?

Comment: Iqbal, thanks for your response. That was actually the first thing I did. Took the exact same full command from the igrep window and ran it in a terminal. Ran fine with same results and didnot give any errors. I honestly never used rgrep, but I found the igrep.el library and customized some of it as a small project, and now my grep command is dependent on the modified version.

Comment: You're asking 3 questions at once which isn't productive. 1: either reproduce bug with `emacs -q` or show your customizations. It could be some advice that's causing this. 2: read info on edebug. 3: don't know this one.

Comment: Thanks abo abo, I did find the issue with the error. Part of my customization is to use grep-mode in the compilation part so I would have a better buffer for the results. The only issue I am after now is how to highlight the matches.

Comment: `igrep` highlights the matches for me, what is the value of `grep-highlight-matches`?

Comment: Iqbal, I have it set to t. When going through searches using next-error it does highlight the whole line the un-highlight instantly. It does not only highlight the match and it doesnt retain the highlight (it was ever supposed to do that). I am also looking for a way to highlight the matches "on the grep buffer itself".

Comment: Is part of the problem that I am running grep on Solaris OS?
I think grep on solaris doesn't acknowledge the --color option.

Comment: @Ammari, sorry I did not get notified of your comment, `Is part of the problem that I am running grep on Solaris OS?` yes the documentation of `grep-highlight-matches` suggests that this can be the issue. ` It does not only highlight the match and it doesnt retain the highlight (it was ever supposed to do that)` momentary highlight is the indented behaviour AFAIK. `I am also looking for a way to highlight the matches "on the grep buffer itself".`, we can create a wrapper around `igrep` that would do so but there will some side effects, I am posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally setting `grep-highlight-matches` to non-nil should have highlighted the matches in the grep buffer. The documentation says that it uses `--color` option for getting color information for matches and as you say (in the comments) the `grep` command on your OS does not support the `--color` option, this explains why the matches are not already highlighted in the grep buffer.

We can still get highlighting in the `grep` buffer by wrapping the `igrep` command in a custom function and then using Drew Adam's excellent `highlight.el` package to highlight the matches, the following is an example of such a function

```
;; Download highlight.el from [http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight.el]
;; and add it to you load-path
(require 'highlight)

(defface my-grep-highlight `((t :background "blue" :foreground "white")) "Face to highlight grep matches with")

;; You can make this buffer local in *igrep* buffer, I was too lazy
(defvar my-igrep-regex nil "Global var storing the value of last grep pattern")

;; Wrapper around igrep, reads the arguments, sets up the hooks for
;; highlighting matches then calls igrep with the read arguments
(defun my-igrep (program regex files &optional options)
  (interactive
   (igrep-read-args))
  ;; Set the current regexp
  (setq my-igrep-regex regex)
  ;; my-grep-highlight-setup sets the compilation-filter-hook which calls
  ;; us back whenever it inserts some line in the *igrep* buffer this
  ;; gives us a chance to hightlight the matches
  (let ((grep-setup-hook (cons 'my-grep-highlight-setup grep-setup-hook)))
    ;; Call `igrep'
    (igrep program regex files options)))

(defun my-grep-highlight-setup ()
  ;; Setup a hook so that we are called back every time a line
  ;; is inserted in *igrep* buffer
  (add-hook 'compilation-filter-hook 'my-highlight-regexp t t))

(defun my-highlight-regexp ()
  ;; compilation-filter-start is bound to the start of inserted line
  (goto-char compilation-filter-start)
  ;; Highlight from start of line to end, this assumes the lines
  ;; output by grep are of the format <filename>:<line_no>:matches
  ;; Thanks a lot Drew Adams for this awesome function, it allows
  ;; us to highlight just a group of given regexp
  (hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end (format ":[0-9]+:.*\\(%s\\)" my-igrep-regex)
                               'my-grep-highlight nil  nil 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Iqbal. I was trying to incorporate your snippet of code into my modified version of grep but I get this error:
Symbol's value as variable is void: hi-lock-interactive-patterns

Comment: Iqbal, I updated my question with the code that I am changing based on your wrapper. Basically I copied (with-current-buffer...) to the end of the grep function. But as I mentioned above, I get this error:
Symbol's value as variable is void: hi-lock-interactive-patterns –

Comment: Hi @Ammari, check the latest answer this will highlight the token you are grepping for, it does not have the drawback the previous answer had.

Comment: `Symbol's value as variable is void: hi-lock-interactive-patterns` oh sorry I should have checked the variable before using it anyways you do not need that code now

Comment: Worked!
Much appreciated.

Comment: By the way, I already load highlight-symbol.el library. I will investigate whether I could use it's functions instead of loading highlight.el.

Comment: I doubt you can use hightlight-symbol.el because in this case we are highlighting a particular (group) regexp, that is why the rest of the occurences (for example the occurence of the regexp in filepath or in the grep command) do not get highlighted, that said I do not use highlight-symbol so I maybe wrong, best of luck. I am glad I could help

Comment: Iqbal, your solution works flawlessly when searching using grep, sometimes I use gid to limit the search to defined structures/functions excluding comments. I tried applying your technique mentioned here but reached dead end. Could you please check my other question on the matter? It has the code I am using as well. Thanks.